# Can I use a power supply with the same voltage but a different amperage?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, amperage

I have an old router with a 12v 1.5a rating, and its power supply died so I'm using a 12v 1.2a power supply.

I have a MIDI keyboard with a 9V 500mA rating and I have a 9V 200mA power supply and one with a 9V 1A rating.

If I don't have the exact amperage, should I use higher or lower?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the exact one, use a higher one. Devices draw as much current as they need; the current shown on a power supply is a maximum. It's the voltage that's fixed.